# SQL: Window function after Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: Subscriptions and Items:

Subscriptions (sub_id PK, user_id, value)
Downloads (download_id PK, user_id, category_id)

My goal is to get a result table of form (user_id, sum_subscription_value, num_download_categories). In other words: each row is unique to a user_id, in which the total value of subscriptions that user has purchased is given alongside the number of categories the user has downloaded things from.

I've attempted by solving using the following code, but the categories aren't being counted correctly. I think the issue might be the join, as the value rows are being repeated, but I'm not sure how to exactly circumvent the issue. Any help is appreciated

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT subscriptions.user_id, 
    SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION by subscriptions.user_id, category_id) AS user_purchases,
    COUNT(category_id) OVER (PARTITION by subscriptions.user_id) AS user_downloads
FROM subscriptions
LEFT JOIN downloads on subscriptions.user_id = downloads.user_id;
```

Comment: Summarize each table by user id and then join those two subqueries.

Comment: ...no window function needed.  Might need a Full Outer Join if can have downloads without subscriptions...

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to get a result table of form (user_id, sum_subscription_value, num_download_categories).

One method is to aggregate before joining.  But in this case, I suppose that a user could be missing from either table.  And aggregating before would require `full join` to avoid losing data.

Instead, you can use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select user_id,
       sum(value) as subscription_value,
       count(distinct category_id) as num_categories
from ((select user_id, value, null as category_id
       from subscriptions
      ) union all
      (select user_id, NULL as value, category_id
       from downloads
      )
     ) sd
group by user_id;
```